# Why http not appended when saving a model?

Tags: django, django-models

I have a model with a URLField named 'website'. When I add a record through the admin form, and give value for 'website' as *www.ex.com*, 'http' is appended. But, when I add a record from code, http is not appended

```
object.website = 'www.ex.com'
object.save()
```

How can I make sure 'http' is appended when saving the record in the code.

I am using Django 1.5

Comment: maybe admin form has a different object method?

Answer (score 2):

That is because the form field responsible for handling the input, [forms.fields.URLField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#urlfield) validates the input. The model field responsible for storing the input, [models.fields.URLField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#urlfield) only stores the input.

If you want the validation of the URLField, you could override `save()` and do some validation on certain fields. However, the easiest would be to include `http://` in the code yourself.